# Extract a string from vcf file

Tags: regex, grep, vcf-variant-call-format

I need to extract `RS=368138379` string from following lines in a `vcf` file of few thousand millions lines. I am wondering how can we use `grep -o ""` and regular expression to quickly extract that?

```
AF_ESP=0.0001;ALLELEID=359042;CLNDISDB=MedGen:C0678202,OMIM:266600;CLNDN=Inflammatory_bowel_disease_1;CLNHGVS=NC_000006.11:g.31779521C>T;CLNREVSTAT=no_assertion_criteria_provided;CLNSIG=association;CLNVC=single_nucleotide_variant;CLNVCSO=SO:0001483;GENEINFO=HSPA1L:3305;MC=SO:0001583|missense_variant;ORIGIN=4;RS=368138379
```

Thanks very much indeed.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried something like, cat File | grep "RS=(*?)" and grep -o 'RS\=\*\;?' all failes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say `text.log` contains your log you can use:

```
grep -oE "RS=[0-9]+" test.log
```

If you want to print also the line numbers:

```
grep -noE "RS=[0-9]+" test.log
```

Answer (score 1):

Something along the lines of `RS=\d+` should do the trick for the expression you're looking for.

Comment: Really appreciate your help, grep -oE "RS=\d+" clinvar.vcf works great for my case.

Answer (score 0):

Best to avoid using [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) to parse VCF/BCF files. Use [bcftools query](https://samtools.github.io/bcftools/bcftools.html#query) instead:

```
bcftools query -f '%INFO/RS\n' -e 'INFO/RS="."' clinvar.vcf.gz
```

A simple `zgrep -oE "RS=[0-9]+" clinvar.vcf.gz` will miss RS values for records that contain more than one ID, which can be pipe-delimited:

```
##INFO=<ID=RS,Number=.,Type=String,Description="dbSNP ID (i.e. rs number)">
```

Number is `.` when the number of possible values varies, is unknown, or is unbounded. Please see: https://samtools.github.io/hts-specs/VCFv4.2.pdf